# Dockerfile COPY file generated by RUN sh script

Tags: java, spring, docker, copy, sh

I want to automate the building and execution of a java spring web service by using Docker.

I run a script from the dockerfile that generate a settings.xml file. I want to copy that file in the image, but because RUN create a new container (I think?) the build can't find the generated file.

Here is the begining of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./script.sh

COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/
```

and there is the output...

[image]

How can I copy the settings.xml file that was generated by my sh script?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does your script put the `settings.xml` file? If your script runs in `/app` and if the script creates the file in its working directory I would expect the result to be placed in `/app/settings.xml` but you are trying to copy `/settings.xml`. Also `COPY` copies from the host. Use `cp` command to copy within a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` copies from the host to the image. If you want to copy from the image to the image, you use the 'normal' `cp` command.

You're right that each RUN statement runs in a separate shell. But since your generated file is stored in the file system, it'll work if you do it in different RUN statements.

But let's do it in one RUN statement to only get 1 new layer in the image:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./script.sh && \
    cp settings.xml /root/.m2/
```

You can also use `mv` to move the file if you don't need a copy to stay in `/app`.

Answer (score 1):

By executing `RUN script.sh` the file will be generated inside the container. Thus it cannot be copied to the image using the `COPY` Dockerfile command. Instead you could `mv` the file inside the container to the desired destination:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN ./script.sh \
  && mv /path/to/settings.xml /root/.m2/
```